# Resource calendar with approval sending approval emails with "No response required"

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, calendar

[Note: this appeared to be the most applicable Stack site to post this into - apologies if wrong]

Strange situation.  I've configured up resource calendar in Office 365 to act as a shared holiday calendar with myself approving and rejecting requests made to the calendar.  This works perfectly if an individual generates a calendar request in the resource calendar.

However, if they invite the Room Resource to an existing meeting request / appointment in their own calendar - I receive an email explicitly stating that "this in-policy resource request was forwarded to you for your approval" but the "Accept" and "Reject" buttons are not shown, only the "No Response Required".

My thinking is that the user, by creating the request in their own calendar, has automatically accepted the request.  By updating their own request to include the resource, Exchange / Office 365 is not creating a new approve-able request in the resource calendar, which would subsequently create the approval email, but it simply updates their request which cannot be approved from the resource calendar.

I've been through the various settings, but cannot find any solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the applicable Stack site. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to approve/reject appointments, the users need to be submitting Meeting Requests to the calendar.

Since the room is automatically approving requests, there may be a settings conflict.

I recommend you check out settings using `Get-CalendarProcessing -Identity resourcecalendar | FL`.  You may find some properties misconfigured. Possibilities include:

```
TentativePendingApproval          
AllBookInPolicy                     
AllRequestInPolicy
RemoveForwardedMeetingNotifications
```

If you want to include the output of the `Get-CalendarProcessing` command above for this mailbox it might help.